# What is variable for "/app/build/" folder in Android?

Tags: android, jenkins, buildpath

Currently Jenkins team is using "${buildDir}" for variable of "/build/" folder in Android project.
I need the variable of "/app/build/" folder since Jenkins should support both Service and Application.
(Path for application : "/app/build/" | Path for service : "/service/build/")

Jenkins team already tried "${project.buildDir}", but they failed.

What is correct variable for "/app/build/" or "/service/build/" folder in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the wiki of Jenkins:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables

Maybe one of the variables can be used to get the data you need.
I think that should help `BUILD_URL`, `JOB_NAME`, or `WORKSPACE`.